# Show disjoint $\theta$-sets in the plane is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $\theta$-set be the union of a circle with one of its chords. Show that any collection of disjoint $\theta$-sets in the plane is countable?

I cannot understand the question and I do not know where to start with, could anyone kindly help? Thanks.

Comment: Probably similar to [Prove by elementary methods: the plane cannot be covered by countably many copies of the letter “Y”](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014171/prove-by-elementary-methods-the-plane-cannot-be-covered-by-countably-many-copie).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro The "Y result" you link to is easier than showing every disjoint collection of Y's is countable, isn't it?

Comment: @zhw: You're correct. I commented too quickly (I think I googled-and-wrote this just before I had to leave for some reason) and didn't look carefully enough at what I linked to. Better are [... 8-signs ...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185466/prove-that-any-family-of-disjoint-8-signs-on-the-plane-is-countable) AND [... letter T's ...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763826/prove-that-there-can-be-at-most-countably-many-disjoint-letter-ts-in-the-plane) AND [... 8 signs...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78018/countable-or-uncountable-set-8-signs).

Comment: @zhw: I believe these problems originated from R. L. Moore's 1928 paper [Concerning Triods in the Plane and the Junction Points of Plane Continua](http://www.pnas.org/content/14/1/85.citation). Googling the phrase "triodic continua" turns up a lot of literature. Also of interest is Timothy Chow's [6 January 1990 sci.math question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/KXyOW2K3l9g). No, not THAT Timothy Chow, but Herbert Enderton did contribute in that sci.math thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A chord is just a straight line segment between two points on the circle (like in the letter $\theta$!)

There is a standard trick to answer these problems but I actually think it's instructive to consider first just a disjoint collection of circles in the plane. Must this collection be countable? The answer is 'no'. If you understand the example of an uncountable such family, you will begin to see why the addition of chords to each of the circles must help.

Comment: Could you kindly tell the difference between the two situations (circle vs $\theta$)? I have thought on it but quite do not see the true reason. That has to be related to the fact that the chord is "straight" but I fail to see precisely the details. And what happens to "swallows" (i.e. degenerate Y's, like $\curlyvee$)? Thank so much for your help.